# Debugging: Divide by three, multiply by two(Codeforces)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Here is the link to the problem: https://codeforces.com/contest/977/problem/D

Here's the correct code to the problem:

```
n = int(input())
l = list(map(int, input().split()))
def conv(n):
    i = 0
    while n % 2 == 0:
        i += 1
        n /= 2
    return (-n, i)
 
l.sort(key=conv)
print(*l)
```

I am not able to understand how the `key = conv` is working, on what basis and how the list(`l`) is getting sorted?

**EDIT:**

Let's take the example when `l` = [4,8,6,3,12,9]. Now instead of `return (-n,i)`, I do `print(-n,i)`. The values of `-n,i` are as stated below:

```
-1.0 3
-3.0 1
-3 0
-3.0 2
-9 0
```

Now according to me, `l` should be [-9,-3,-3,-3,0,0,-1,1,2,3] but clearly this is not the case as in the answer `l` is [9,3,6,12,4,8].Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at what are the values to be returned for each element:

**Element** ...... **-1*n(t1)** ...... **i(t2)**

4..................... -1 ..............        2

8..................... -1 ...............3

6....................         -3 ..............        1

3....................         -3 ..............        0

12....................        -3 ..............        2

9....................         -9 ..............        0

Now the elements will be sorted based on comparisons first between values of **t1** and if they are equal then on the basis of **t2**.
(*Ascending Order*)

Let's rank those:

9    ......->......    -9,0

3    ......->......    -3,0

6    ......->......    -3,1

12   ......->......    -3,2

4    ......->......    -1,2

8    ......->......    -1,3

In the above order, the list is sorted using the function **conv**.

**Sorted list -> [9,3,6,12,4,8]**

Answer (score 0):

`key=conv` means that list `l` is sorted using the `conv` function. Each element is sent as input to `conv`. The list is then finally sorted based on the list of outputs from `conv`

Comment: That's what I am not able to understand. Take the list as:
4 8 6 3 12 9
The output is :
9 3 6 12 4 8 
But I am not able to understand as to how this output is coming

Comment: The sorting method will compute a key for each element by calling conv, and sort according to that. Try creating a list by calling conv on all the elements you have and then sort it. That is the order you get when you sort with the key argument. So the elements come out in the order that their keys are sorted by, not the “natural” order.